# Overlapping points when using fill aesthetic in ggplot2 geom_dotplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I use `aes(fill=...)` to indicate factor levels in a `geom_dotplot`, points of different factor levels overlap each other. Especially with large datasets, this becomes troublesome.

Below I have included a minimal example and figure, in which I first plot a dataset without colouring factor levels, and then I add `fill` to indicate factor levels, which leads to points overlapping each other. How can I avoid this?

I am aware of a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30582280/fill-argument-creates-overlapping-points-in-geom-dotplot-in-r); however, the answers given do not resolve this issue.

```
library("ggplot2")

n <- 200
x <- data.frame(x = sample(x = letters[1:3], size = n, replace = TRUE),
                y = rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                a = sample(x = letters[4:5], size = n, replace = TRUE))

p1 <- ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = y))
p1 <- p1 + geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")
p2 <- ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = a))
p2 <- p2 + geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center")
```

[image: minimal_example_dotplot]

Comment: Experiment playing with `geom_dotplot` options, ie: `method="histodot"`, and `dotsize = .5`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somehow this combination of arguments, with stackgroups=T combined with binpositions="all" gives a nice result but only centered for the central level of x variable.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=a)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", 
               stackdir = "centerwhole", 
               method="dotdensity",
               stackgroups = T,
               binpositions="all")
```

[image]

A little bit more complicated construction could yield a result similar to what you want: it uses grid.arrange and a special function to share a common legend (see [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs) for the code of the `grid_arrange_shared_legend` function)

```
for (i in 1:3){
  assign(paste0("g", i), ggplot(x %>% filter(x==levels(x$x)[i]), aes(x = x, y = y, fill=a)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3.5, 3.5))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", method="dotdensity", stackgroups = T, binpositions="all"))
}
grid_arrange_shared_legend(g1, g2, g3)
```

[image]

Comment: The first solution now works fine. I guess this feature has been updated since 2016. The key argument is stackgroups = T, but this requires that binpositions="all". I think stackdir = "center" is better than "centerwhole".