# How do I use color in a geom_dotplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dotplot:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center')
```

which renders as

[image]

I want to color the dots by manufacturer. If I add a `fill` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy, fill = manufacturer)) +
  geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center')
```

it renders as

[image]

It looks like adding color has defeated the stacking algorithm somehow, causing the dots to overlap. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `stackdir="centerwhole"`

Comment: Or maybe `stackgroups = TRUE`

Comment: I'm not sure, but `geom_beeswarm` from package *ggbeeswarm* might be an option.

Comment: @aosmith this seems like the best option, if you put it in an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy, fill = manufacturer)) +
  geom_dotplot(stackdir = "centerwhole",stackgroups = TRUE,
  binpositions = "all", binaxis = "y", binwidth = 1)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you need everything to be perfectly centered, I'd review [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38479399/4421870) of writing a `for` loop to plot three separate charts (one for each factor level), using a shared legend.

## Edit:

And here's the chart following the linked process of using a function to combine three plots with the same legend:

[image]

Comment: Yikes, pretty ugly without the centering. No link for "this example"?

Comment: I followed the above template, and it produces your desired result. I'd recommend using @epsilone's modified version of the originally linked `grid_arrange_shared_legend` function that let's you pass `nrow` and `ncol`

Comment: And here's the original implementation from the ggplot devs: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs

Answer (score 5):

Using `geom_beeswarm` from package *ggbeeswarm* is an option.  It doesn't center the even numbered rows of dots quite the same way, but the point color seems to work out better than `geom_dotplot`.

```
library(ggbeeswarm)

ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, hwy, color = manufacturer)) +
     geom_beeswarm(size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I wish I could accept both this and Mako212's answer, but I went with theirs because it more literally answered the question of how to add color to a `geom_dotplot`, and the result looks more symmetric. This answer wins for simplicity of use though, and I didn't know about `ggbeeswarm`, so thanks!