# geom_dotplot with vertical stacking and colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've looked at [How do I use color in a geom_dotplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444848/how-do-i-use-color-in-a-geom-dotplot) , but I don't understand how it applies to my current use case.

For this example:

```r
dfc <- structure(list(g = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), r = c(9, 2, 
2, 10, 7, 5.5, 5.5, 8, 4, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I would like to get the points from both groups stacked appropriately, with appropriate colors. If I specify `group=1` I get the right stacking but no colors:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dfc, aes(color=g, fill=g)) + geom_dotplot(aes(x=r, group = 1), binwidth = 0.2)
```

[image]

If I don't specify `group=1` I get the colors, but the points are stacked:

```r
ggplot(dfc, aes(color=g, fill=g)) + geom_dotplot(aes(x=r), binwidth = 0.2)
```

[image]

I can get close with `ggstance::position_dodgev()`, but not quite:

```r
ggplot(dfc, aes(color=g, fill=g)) + geom_dotplot(position=ggstance::position_dodgev(height=0.025), aes(x=r), binwidth = 0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for. Let me know if this wasn't the answer you're looking for

```
ggplot(dfc, aes(x=r, y=g, color=g, fill=g)) + 
  geom_dotplot(stackgroups = TRUE, binwidth = 0.25, method = "histodot") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 2, to = 10, by = 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Following the linked to post in the question and after some trial and error, I came up with this.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dfc, aes(x=r)) + 
  geom_dotplot(
    aes(color = g, fill = g), 
    stackgroups = TRUE,
    binpositions = "all", 
    binwidth = 0.2
  )
```

[image]